# Redux-form FieldArray, handleSubmit' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm working to use a redux-form FieldArray. I'm having challenges connecting the form w the actual react component. When I try to submit the form, I get the following error: `error    'handleSubmit' is not defined`

The file is below. Am I building this form correctly in my React component? Any idea why handleSubmit is erroring?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, FieldArray, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as inviteActions from '../../actions/inviteActions';

let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error}}) =>
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} name="email" type="email"/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>

let renderEmails = ({fields, meta: {submitFailed, error}}) =>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add Email</button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((email, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        {index > 2 && <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Email"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />}
        <Field
          name={email}
          component={renderEmailField}
          label={`Email #${index + 1}`}
        />
      </li>
    )}
    {submitFailed && error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
  </ul>

let EmailsForm = ({handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting}) =>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <FieldArray name="emails" component={renderEmails} />
    <div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
        Clear Values
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>


class InvitePage extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data)
    this.props.actions.createInvites(data);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Invites</h1>
        <EmailsForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

EmailsForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
  initialValues: {
    emails: ['', '', '']
  },
  validate(values) {
    const errors = {}
    if (!values.emails || !values.emails.length) {
      errors.emails = {_error: 'At least one email must be entered'}
    }
    else {
      let emailsArrayErrors = []
      values.emails.forEach((email, emailIndex) => {
        const emailErrors = {}
        if (email == null || !email.trim()) {
          emailsArrayErrors[emailIndex] = 'Required'
        }
      })
      if (emailsArrayErrors.length) {
        errors.emails = emailsArrayErrors
      }
    }
    return errors
  }
})(EmailsForm)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(inviteActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvitePage);
```

Comment: I think you need `this.handleSubmit`, and possibly bound to since you call a contextual this inside your handle submit function. So it should be `<EmailsForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided onSubmit function as a prop to EmailsForm. You can pass it in two ways:

```
EmailsForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
  ...
  onSubmit: () => {}
  ... 
})(EmailsForm)
```

or you can pass `onSubmit` as a prop while calling `EmailsForm`

```
<EmailsForm onSubmit={() => {}} />
```

In your case, you have to write like this:

```
<EmailsForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

According to me, if you can re-use these small components `renderEmailField, renderEmails, EmailsForm`, then you can create them as a separate component as you have done now.

I would recommend, you should not separate EmailsForm from InvitePage class as you will have to pass all props from InvitePage to EmailsForm as your requirement grows. InvitePage is not serving any other purpose as of now other than passing onSubmit function.

```
class InvitePage extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.props.actions.createInvites(data);
  }

  render() {
    const { pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Invites</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> // react recommends we should not bind function here. Either bind that in constructor or write handleSubmit like I have written.
          <FieldArray name="emails" component={renderEmails} />

          <div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
            <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
              Clear Values
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

InvitePage = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
  initialValues: {
    emails: ['', '', ''],
  },
  validate(values) {
    ...
  }
})(InvitePage)
```

Hope it works.

Try to use **const** rather than **let** if you are not changing the value of any variable.

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on the entire file? I have all these `let` statements outside of the `class InvitePage` - Is that ok? It feels really messy but I'm new to React so I can't figure out if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: Thanks RITESH, would you mind helping me understand how I can combine the two?

Comment: thank you... I was able to make the updates. only thing wrong is when I click submit, the page refreshes. the `handleSubmit()` isn't being called

Comment: this ended up working `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>` - any concerns?

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly pass a callback function to handleSubmit like this.

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;


    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field name="firstName" component={this.renderField} type="text" className="curvedBorder" label="First Name" />
          ...
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
}


onSubmit(values) {
    // handle form submission here.
    console.log(values);
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!